# How to use .net metrics for version 4.8

Tags: c#, ninjatrader

I have custom strategies on ninja trader which is tied in to Net 4.8. How do i add telemetry info as the Microsoft site shows headlining for "applies to NET Framework 4.6.1 and later versions"   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/metrics-instrumentation

Tried to add the metric package at top but the compiler cannot detect it

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics.Metrics;// cannot find the package                 
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
    }
}
```

see the fiddle targeting ver 4.8
[Fiddle link](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SdeFd3)

Comment: See following.  System.Diagnostic.Metrics only is found in Net 6 or later (CORE) : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/metrics-instrumentation  You are trying to use it with Net 4.8 which is older than Net 6.

Comment: How can i add metrics for .net 4.8 even if i have to use opentelemetry? I am looking for some samples and cannot find it for the console version. the latest examples seem to leverage  System.diagnostic.metrics

Comment: See following Github project : https://github.com/Recognos/Metrics.NET/tree/master

Comment: The referenced article does say 4.6.1 ot later, so you should be able to get it to work (though there isn't much there to tell you what to do). What do you mean by _"but the compiler cannot detect it"_? Have you included the correct NuGet package? A `using` directive isn't enough